# I'm using a Python fingerprint sensor in Java,

Tags: java, python, jython, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint

```
public void fingerprint() {
    System.setProperty("python.cachedir.skip", "true");
    PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();
    pi.execfile("/usr/share/doc/python-fingerprint/examples/example_search.py");
}
```

> File "/home/pi/pyfingerprint/src/debian/python-fingerprint/usr/share/doc/python-fingerprint/examples/example_search.py", line 12, in 
>       from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint
>   ImportError: No module named pyfingerprint

I'm using a Python fingerprint sensor in Java, and the error has come up.
I do not know how to do this ...; help me.

Comment: Try `pip install pyfingerprint`

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyfingerprint (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyfingerprint I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the pyfingerprint folder in this repo https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint/tree/Development/src/files to your site-packages folder

Comment: Download the pyfingerprint folder from the above url then fi using windows go to "C:\<path to your python installation directory>\Lib\site-packages" and paste the downloaded pyfingerprint there.